# $\Theta(polynomial)$ vs. n choose k run time

Tags: calculus, algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Say I have an algorithm with input (G,k). G an undirected graph with with n vertices and runs in time $n \choose k$. Why is this not a polynomial run time for all n and k in |(G,k)|$\geq$ log(k) the length of the input: run time $\Theta(p(|(G,k)|))$ where p is a polynomial?

I know that $(n/k)^k \leq$ $n\choose k$.

certainly if k=floor(n/2) we get that $n \choose k$ $\geq (n/k)^k$ $\geq 2^{k}$

What does it mean to NOT be polynomial time? why is it that lower bounding by an exponential means the run time is no longer polynomial?

Comment: Let's recall some definitions. Let $T(n)$ be running time for your algorithm where $n$ is your input size. Then we say $T(n)$ is of polynomial time if we can find some $c > 0$ such that $T(n) \le n^c$ for sufficiently large $n$. So the idea is that for large enough input, the running time of the algorithm is bounded above by a polynomial function, which cannot grow too fast, hence a feasible problem from the complexity theory pov. Now to answer your question, it is because any exponential function with positive exponent grows faster than any polynomial function for sufficiently large input.

Comment: it's exponential in k which is a varying input. as k increases it approaches n/2 which means your algorithm is exponential of order n/2.